# How to create a bar chart made up of very small squares

Tags: svg, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am trying to use d3 to create a chart which will end up being almost like a bar chart. However, I would like to accomplish this by using very small individual squares. Something like the image below but ignoring the random squares dotted around:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yyi5e.jpg

Each square represents a vote (or group of votes depending on how many votes are made on a given day) and can have 3 possible values, each with a different shade of blue, i.e. light blue, blue and dark blue.

One example I have already found is http://bost.ocks.org/mike/miserables/ but I would like to convert this style in to a bar chart.

I have already attempted at doing the markup in HTML using tables and divs, but this got widely out of control and ending up massively slowing down the page loading speed -- hence the use of SVG instead.

Any ideas on how to approach this would be appreciated.

Comment: You'd be better off using canvas than either SVG or HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basis for what you want to do is the stacked bar chart: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208

However, there are a few things you will need to take into account. The y and x axes must be proportional so you will have to carefully consider:

- the size of the graph
- the number of data points
- the max value each data point can have

and select a height, width and "value" for each tick - each square.

I've made a demonstration fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/sa5RK/

It assumes a few things (for simplicity!):

- Each tick is one value
- The height & width of the box is set

  ```
  var boxheight = 6;
  ```
- the height / width can be dynamic based on the size of the box and data values

  ```
  var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 80, left: 40},
      width = boxheight * data.length;


  var max = d3.max(data, function(d){return d.a + d.b + d.c});
  var height = max * boxheight;
  ```

I hope that's enough to get you started!

The other key thing which will help you out, is learning how each data joined selection can be set to a variable, then selecting inside of it will allow you access to the outside bound data. eg. below, each data group (value in the original array) -> has types (a,b or c) -> has rectangles

```
var groups = svg.selectAll(".group")
    .data(data)
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("transform", function(d,i){return "translate(" + x(i) + ", 0)"})
        .attr("class", "group")

var types = groups.selectAll(".type")
    .data(function(d){return d.offsets})
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("transform", function(d){ return translate(0,y(d.y1))})
        .attr("class", "type")
        .attr("fill", function(d){return color(d.type)})

types.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d){return d3.range(0,d.value)})
      .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("height", boxheight-0.5)
        .attr("width", boxheight-0.5)
        .attr("y", function(d){ return boxheight * d })
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Will mark as answered as looks more than enough to get me started!

Comment: Great! If you have more specific questions, they'll probably get a more focussed answer. https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/API-Reference is also very useful and extensive.